# Restructure Repo on cloning

Tags: git

Can I re-struct a repository (submodule) on cloning time without changing the structure on the server repository? 
For example:
Assume now I have the following

```
Repo:MyRepo
       |
       |___SubModule: mysub
```

This how the submodule looks like on the server

```
Repo:mysub 
       |
       |___Folder:A
                  |
                  |___a.txt,aa.txt

       |___Folder:B
                  |
                  |___b.txt,bb.txt

       |___Folder:C
                  |
                  |___c.txt,cc.txt
```

When I clone this repo as a submodule I need to get it on my local machine as

```
Repo:mysub 
       |
       |___Folder:D
                  |
                  |___a.txt,aa.txt,b.txt,bb.txt

       |___Folder:E
                  |
                  |___c.txt,cc.txt
```

i.e. to restruct it in a way each file map to its equivalent without losing the history just a change in the paths.

Comment: TMTOWTDI. 1. You could keep the submodule intact, and use symbolic links (`ln -s`) to provide the path access you need. You can even check those into `MyRepo`. 2. You could have a git hook move files for you. 3. You could manually run a script that would move files for you.

Comment: you cannot do it in git.

Comment: @amphetamachine I gotcha point 2 and 3 but for point 1 I think I didn't get what you mean by using symbolic links? Any link or example for illustration?